# MySQL Workbench error 1022

Tags: mysql-workbench

hello everybody I'm studying database and I use MySQL Workbench.

I try to create 3 table but it produces a problem:

> ERROR: Error 1022: Can't write duplicate key in table 'paziente' SQL
>   Code:

```sql
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `gestione di prenotazione`.`paziente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gestione di prenotazione`.`paziente` (
  `tesseraSanitario` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `codfsc` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `luogo di nascita` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `dataNascita` DATE NULL,
  `tipo` VARCHAR(1) NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `AUSL` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tesseraSanitario`, `codfsc`),
  INDEX `cf_idx` (`codfsc` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `cf_UNIQUE` (`codfsc` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `cf`
    FOREIGN KEY (`codfsc`)
    REFERENCES `gestione di prenotazione`.`persona` (`cf`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

in follow there are 3 table:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `gestione di prenotazione` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `gestione di prenotazione` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `gestione di prenotazione`.`persona`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gestione di prenotazione`.`persona` (
  `cf` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `cognome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `sesso` VARCHAR(1) NULL,
  `indirizzo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `telefono` INT NULL,
  `comune` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cf`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `cf_UNIQUE` (`cf` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `gestione di prenotazione`.`medico`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gestione di prenotazione`.`medico` (
  `idmedico` INT NOT NULL,
  `codicefiscale` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `numero di assistito in carico` INT NULL,
  `numero massimo di assistito` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmedico`, `codicefiscale`),
  INDEX `cf_idx` (`codicefiscale` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `cf_UNIQUE` (`codicefiscale` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `cf`
    FOREIGN KEY (`codicefiscale`)
    REFERENCES `gestione di prenotazione`.`persona` (`cf`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `gestione di prenotazione`.`paziente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gestione di prenotazione`.`paziente` (
  `tesseraSanitario` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `codfsc` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `luogo di nascita` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `dataNascita` DATE NULL,
  `tipo` VARCHAR(1) NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `AUSL` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tesseraSanitario`, `codfsc`),
  INDEX `cf_idx` (`codfsc` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `cf_UNIQUE` (`codfsc` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `cf`
    FOREIGN KEY (`codfsc`)
    REFERENCES `gestione di prenotazione`.`persona` (`cf`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: your key is duplicating

Answer (score 0):

Your table `paziente`'s primary key is duplicating. So in SQL you cannot add duplicate keys as a primary key. Every primary key should be unique.